# error C2512 but i have default constructor available

Tags: c++

my code have error (error C2512: 'Node' : no appropriate default constructor available)
but i have default constructor why ???
my error location commented in code Please help me

Node.h

```
#pragma once
#include "stat.h"
#include "Automata.h"
#include <cstdlib>

class Node
{
    friend class Automata;
    friend class stat_a;
    friend stat_a* makeauto(char *str);
    friend int main();
private:
    stat_a* mess;
    char data;//harfi ke ba in masir estefadeh mishe :)
    Node *next;//node badi dar araye node ha class stat_a :)
public:
    Node()
    {
        mess = NULL;
        next = NULL;
    };
};
```

stat.h

```
#pragma once
#include "Node.h" 
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
class stat_a
{
    friend class Automata;
    friend class Node;
    friend int main();
private:
    bool is_final_stat_a;        //aya final stat_a hast ???
    int  stat_a_num;              //shomareh halat 0,1,2,...
    Node *last;                  //akharin node dar araye node haye neshan dahande masir
    Node *first;                //Avalin node dar araye node haye neshan dahande masir
public:
    void add(char d,stat_a * a)//ezafeh kardan masiri ke ba estefadeh
    {                       //az harf (char d ) be halat (stat_a a) miravad
        if(first == NULL)
        {
            first = new Node;//error is here
            first->data = d;
            first->mess = a;
            last=first;
        }
        else
        {
            last->next = new Node ;//erorr is here
            last=last->next;
            last->data=d;
            last->next=NULL;
            last->mess=a;
        }
    };

    /***********************************************************************/

    void print()
    {
        cout<<stat_a_num<<"========> is final_stat_a : "<<is_final_stat_a<<endl;
        Node *a;

        a=first;
        while(a != NULL)
        {
            cout<<"========> By '"<<a->data<<"' go to stat "<<a->mess->stat_a_num<<endl;
            a=a->next;
        }
    };

    stat_a()
    {
        last=NULL;
        first=NULL;
        is_final_stat_a=false;
    };

    ~stat_a(void);
};
```

I have default constructor available why error

Comment: Please delete comments on your local language next time you'll ask for help on stackoverflow, it's just a noise for people who not familiar with your language, distracting from real problem.

Comment: You have a cyclic include dependency. That cannot work.

Comment: Don't make friends excessively like you do, only keep it for when it's really needed (which in 99.99% of cases is never).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's a classical example of circular dependency. The header file `Node.h` depends on the header file `stat.h` which depends on `Node.h` and so on.

Since you only declare a pointer variable of type `stat_h` in `Node`, you don't need to include the header file for that, it's enough to declare the class `stat_a`:

```
#pragma once
#include "Automata.h"
#include <cstdlib>

class stat_a;  // Declare the class, so the compiler know there's a class by this name

class Node
{
    // ...

private:
    stat_a* mess;  // Works because you're only declaring a pointer

    // ...

public:
    // ...
};
```

Then in the `stat.h` header when you include `Node.h` there is no longer a circular dependency.

Comment: @Rezaagha If you modified `Node.h` as per my answer, and kept `stat.h` as it is, then the errors should have gone away.

Comment: @Rezaagha By the way, I hope that `Automata.h` doesn't include `stat.h` or you still have the circular dependency.

Answer (score 1):

Replace

```
Node();
{
    mess = NULL;
    next = NULL;
}
```

with

```
Node()
{
    mess = NULL;
    next = NULL;
};
```